# Is there a term for a function whose first derivatives exist but aren't necessarily continuous?

Tags: calculus

$C^0$ means continuous and $C^1$ (in what I've read) means first derivatives exist and are continuous.  Is there a term for first derivatives existing but not  necessarily being continuous?

Comment: Sure: "differentiable." If all you assert about a function is that it is differentiable, you imply nothing about whether the derivative is continuous.

Comment: So would 'differentiable' be C^(1/2) ?

Comment: $C^{1/2}$ isn't a notation that's used. Honestly we don't really have a special symbol for the space of all differentiable functions.

Comment: bitesizebo -- thanks, that's what I thought

Comment: You **definitely** don't want to use $C^{1/2},$ because ${\cal C}^{\alpha}$ for $0 < \alpha < 1$ is fairly standard for Hölder continuous of order $\alpha.$

Answer (score 1):

Sure: "differentiable."

If all you assert about a function is that it is differentiable, you imply nothing about whether the derivative is continuous. There is no standard notation for the class of all differentiable functions. Many theorems in advanced calculus need a function to be $C^1$, not just differentiable.

Comment: FYI, I think I've seen $\cal D$ or maybe ${\cal D}^1$ used occasionally for finitely differentiable, and ${\cal D}^*$ or maybe ${\cal D}^{*1}$ used for finitely or infinitely (of the same sign) differentiable, but I don't have the time now to track down any such references, and besides, the usage would have been sufficiently localized to not be considered standard.